# Chakra-paginator - Next.js - Chakra UI - memory leak

Tags: reactjs, next.js, toast, chakra-ui

## Error

My next.js app use chakra-paginator, when I call toast on the page when is used chakra-paginator, browser console shows error:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
> ToastManager@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1627303273546:38352:5

### Find error

I find this bug, becouse when I removed all chakra-paginator components and hooks, Toast works OK.

#### Probably error only in Next.js

When I try it in codesandbox.io only in clear React + TS toast works ok. Problems is between chakra-paginator and next.js i think.

### My code

```
import React, { FC, ChangeEvent, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Grid,
  Center,
  Select,
  ButtonProps,
  Text,
  Button,
  useToast,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import {
  Paginator,
  Container,
  Previous,
  usePaginator,
  Next,
  PageGroup,
} from "chakra-paginator";

const fetchPokemons = (pageSize: number, offset: number) => {
  return fetch(
    `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=${pageSize}&offset=${offset}`
  ).then((res) => res.json());
};

const Poke: FC = () => {
  // react hooks
  const [pokemonsTotal, setPokemonsTotal] = useState<number | undefined>(
    undefined
  );
  const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const toast = useToast();
  // constants
  const outerLimit = 2;
  const innerLimit = 2;

  const {
    isDisabled,
    pagesQuantity,
    currentPage,
    setCurrentPage,
    setIsDisabled,
    pageSize,
    setPageSize,
    offset, // you may not need this most of the times, but it's returned for you anyway
  } = usePaginator({
    total: pokemonsTotal,
    initialState: {
      pageSize: 10,
      currentPage: 1,
      isDisabled: false,
    },
  });

  // effects
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPokemons(pageSize, offset).then((pokemons) => {
      setPokemonsTotal(pokemons.count);
      setPokemons(pokemons.results);
    });
  }, [currentPage, pageSize, offset]);

  // styles
  const baseStyles: ButtonProps = {
    w: 7,
    fontSize: "sm",
  };

  const normalStyles: ButtonProps = {
    ...baseStyles,
    _hover: {
      bg: "green.300",
    },
    bg: "red.300",
  };

  const activeStyles: ButtonProps = {
    ...baseStyles,
    _hover: {
      bg: "blue.300",
    },
    bg: "green.300",
  };

  const separatorStyles: ButtonProps = {
    w: 7,
    bg: "green.200",
  };

  // handlers
  const handlePageChange = (nextPage: number) => {
    // -> request new data using the page number
    setCurrentPage(nextPage);
    console.log("request new data with ->", nextPage);
  };

  const handlePageSizeChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    const pageSize = Number(event.target.value);

    setPageSize(pageSize);
  };

  const handleDisableClick = () => {
    return setIsDisabled((oldState) => !oldState);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Paginator
        isDisabled={isDisabled}
        activeStyles={activeStyles}
        innerLimit={innerLimit}
        currentPage={currentPage}
        outerLimit={outerLimit}
        normalStyles={normalStyles}
        separatorStyles={separatorStyles}
        pagesQuantity={pagesQuantity}
        onPageChange={handlePageChange}
      >
        <Container align="center" justify="space-between" w="full" p={4}>
          <Previous>
            Previous
            {/* Or an icon from `react-icons` */}
          </Previous>
          <PageGroup isInline align="center" />
          <Next>
            Next
            {/* Or an icon from `react-icons` */}
          </Next>
        </Container>
      </Paginator>
      <Center w="full">
        <Button onClick={handleDisableClick}>Disable ON / OFF</Button>
        <Select w={40} ml={3} onChange={handlePageSizeChange}>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="25">25</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
        </Select>
      </Center>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          toast({
            title: "new toast",
            duration: 4000,
          });
        }}
      >
        Toast
      </Button>
      <Grid
        templateRows="repeat(2, 1fr)"
        templateColumns="repeat(5, 1fr)"
        gap={3}
        px={20}
        mt={20}
      >
        {pokemons?.map(({ name }) => (
          <Center p={4} bg="green.100" key={name}>
            <Text>{name}</Text>
          </Center>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};

export default Poke;
```

Toast doesnt works in this code in next.js, but in React.js it works.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue - Were you able to resolve this problem?